# CVC4: settings to syntheize functions over bools with quantifiers?

Tags: smt, quantifiers, cvc4, bounded-quantification

I'm currently using CVC4 to solve formulas of the following form:

```
exists f1, ..., fn . P(f1, ..., fn) /\ forall (b1...bk) . Q(f1,...fn,b1,...bk)
```

Here, the `f1...fn` are functions from some number of `Bool` to `Bool`, and the
`b1...bk` are boolean values.

My problem falls squarely into the `UF` fragment of SMT: it has quantifiers, but no sorts other than Functions and Booleans.

When I try my problem with the default settings on CVC4, it immediately returns Unknown, despite the fact that all my quantification is over finite domains.

The problem is, CVC4 has an *extremely* large number of options for dealing with quantifiers: there's a bunch of `cegqi`, a bunch of `fmf`, there's `mbqi`, etc. I get the impression that most of these were added from specific research projects, and I'd rather not have to read through 20 different papers just to get my solution going.

**My question:** Is there a recommended set of options for solving this kind of problems?

I know it's possible with CVC4, since they competed and performed quite well at the [UF Track](http://smtcomp.sourceforge.net/2017/results-UF.shtml?v=1500632282) of the SMT competition, but I can't find the specifics arguments used for that competition.

Comment: We are running into the same issue using bit-vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "--finite-model-find" which more info can be found here:
[Exactly what quantifiers is SMT complete for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962686/exactly-what-quantifiers-is-smt-complete-for)

If that doesn't work you might want to try looking through the configuration used in the smt-comp:
https://www.starexec.org/starexec/secure/details/configuration.jsp?id=220723 
I found the option there first and then had the stack-overflow question pointed out to me.